# How do I change the Visual Studio Code minimap background colour?

Tags: visual-studio-code, theming

With the introduction of `workbench.experimental.colorCustomizations`, how do I change the background colour of the minimap? Or has that option not been added yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found out it's not related, and is in fact controlled by the syntax theme.